# Using Notification with StopWatch

Tags: android, android-notifications

I use stopwatch in notification / status bar.

- I get stopwatch in `contentText`  with `getFormattedElapsedTime()` . It works BUT stops when I close application. How can I work it even if app closed ?

  ```
  private NotificationManager m_notificationMgr;
  private Notification m_notification;
     // Timer to update the ongoing notification
   private final long mFrequency = 100;    // milliseconds
      private final int TICK_WHAT = 2; 
      private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message m) {
              updateNotification();
              sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(this, TICK_WHAT), mFrequency);
          }
      };

      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          Log.d(TAG, "created");

          m_stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
          m_notificationMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

          createNotification();
      }


  public void createNotification() {
          Log.d(TAG, "creating notification");


          int icon = R.drawable.icon;
          CharSequence tickerText = "Meb";
          long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

          m_notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
          m_notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
          m_notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
      }

      public void updateNotification() {
          // Log.d(TAG, "updating notification");

          Context context = getApplicationContext();
          CharSequence contentTitle = "Mebr";
          CharSequence contentText = getFormattedElapsedTime();

          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TimerFragmentActivity.class);
          PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

          // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the configurations above
          m_notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
          m_notificationMgr.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, m_notification);
      }

      public void showNotification() {
          Log.d(TAG, "showing notification");

          updateNotification();       
          mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(mHandler, TICK_WHAT), mFrequency);
      }

      public void hideNotification() {
          Log.d(TAG, "removing notification");

          m_notificationMgr.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
          mHandler.removeMessages(TICK_WHAT);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update your notification from a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), which can keep running even after the activity is paused or stopped.